$\sigma$-algebra of a.s. finite stopping time
I am trying to solve Exercise 3.4.5 of Stochastic Calculus and Applications by Cohen, Elliott, which reads

For $T$ an a.s. finite stopping time, show that $\mathcal{F}_T \subseteq \mathcal{F}_\infty$,
where if $\infty \notin \mathbb{T}$ we deﬁne $\mathcal{F}_\infty=\bigvee_{t\in \mathbb{T}}\mathcal{F}_t$.

My problem is with almost surly  finite $T$. The solution is easy if we assume the filtration is complete or $T$ is (surely) finite, by writing
$$\forall A\in \mathcal{F}:A=\big(\cup_{t\in\mathbb{T}}A\cap\{T\leq t\}\big)\cup (A\cap\{T=\infty\}).$$
Now $A\cap\{T\leq t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$ so $\big(\cup_{t\in\mathbb{T}}(A\cap\{T\leq t\})\big)\in\mathcal{F}_\infty$ and $\{T=\infty\}$ is either null or $\emptyset$ depending whether we set $T$ to be almost surely finite or just finite.
As far as I can see, up to the point of the exercise, the book does not enforce any assumption of completeness. It does not even introduce a measure at the beginning of chapter 3 and only sets a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.
Is this an error, or is there a way to solve the exercise without assumption on completeness?

It is an error. Your observation is correct.

By their definition, an event $A$ is an element of $\mathcal F_T$ provided $A\in\mathcal F$ and
$$
A\cap\{T\le t\}\in\mathcal F_t,\qquad\forall t\in\Bbb T.
$$
Let's assume time is continuous, so $\Bbb T$ is either $[0,\infty)$ or $[0,\infty]$.
Case 1. $\Bbb T=[0,\infty]$.
Let $A$ be an element of $\mathcal F_T$. Then
$$
A=A\cap\{T\le\infty\}\in\mathcal F_\infty.
$$
Thus $\mathcal F_T\subset \mathcal F_\infty$ rather trivially in this case.
Case 2. $\Bbb T = [0,\infty)$.
Again suppose $A\in \mathcal F_T$. As you observe,
$$
A\cap\{T<\infty\}=\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(A\cap\{T\le n\}\right),
$$
and this event lies in $\mathcal F_\infty$. Now $\{T=\infty\}$ is an element of $\mathcal F_\infty$ because $T$ is a stopping time and
$$
\{T=\infty\}=\{T<\infty\}^c.
$$
But without additional information, the most to be said about $A\cap\{T=\infty\}$ is that it is an element of $\mathcal F$. We have $\mathcal F_\infty\subset \mathcal F$, but the containment may be strict.
If $\mathcal F=\mathcal F_\infty$ then we're done.
If the filtration is complete (as per Definition 3.2.17, page 81) and $T$ is a.s. finite, then $A\cap\{T=\infty\}$ is a null set, hence an element of each $\mathcal F_t$; in this case $A\cap\{T=\infty\}\in\mathcal F_\infty$, so also $A\in \mathcal F_\infty$. Thus $\mathcal F_T\subset\mathcal F_\infty$ provided the filtration is complete. One imagines that the authors were tacitly assuming completeness in posing the exercise the way they did.

Thanks for the detailed answer. You must be right about the tacit assumption since in Def. 3.2.17 they define the original $\sigma$-algebra with $\mathcal{F}^0$ and the completion with $\mathcal{F}$. What threw me off was that they mention this right after Def. 3.1.10: "for $T$ a.s. ﬁnite, we can equally deﬁne $\mathcal{F}T$ as the σ-algebra of events $A \in \mathcal{F}\infty$ (rather than $A \in \mathcal{F}$) such that $A ∩ {T \leq t} \in \mathcal{F}_t$."
